# How to merge 2 projects into 1 using Android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, merge, terminal, nfc

I have a NFC project which read/write information from/to a tag and display it on the screen.I also have a Bluetooth terminal with which I can transfer text from my phone to Computer terminal.My task is to merge these 2 applications into one. I want that, when I read my tag via my phone to send the information to the computer terminal.Can someone explain me the steps I should fallow?I can attached the codes if is necessary but they are big.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use Gradle modules, however without knowing anything about your apps, that's really all that can be said about combining things in Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

If I'm right these are Java programs.So the first idea which came to my mind is that you can create a package on the main project and add all the classes(which you want to combine together) to that package.After that when you want to use a particular class's methods to another, simply import it.
example:

```
import java.util.List;
```

Hope this helps